# Wordpress own RewriteRule doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

When I write *my.domain/my/url* I want to go to other webpage, but I am still on 
*my.domain/my/url* with Error 404

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

    # Here is my RewriteRule
    RewriteRule ^my/url$ //google.pl

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: is your rewrite server module on?

Comment: I don't know how to check it, but on subdomain RewriteRule works, so i gues it is.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer for your htaccess issue. You need to add the folders in the RewriteBase like i did. For example www.domain.com/my/url/ is path of your wordpress then you need to add /my/url/ to rewritebase.

```
   # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /my/url/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
    # END WordPress
```

Comment: My wp folder is in my.domain so  RewriteBase / seams ok to me.
I wont to make custom url in the same domain when I write my.domain/my/url i wuld go to other side

Comment: @KrzysiekKukiz It will work for the same domain. I have mentioned google for just an example. It will work like this yourdomain.com/my/url